# Oracle SQL Developer - Copyright (c) 2005, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved. Error

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I use linux Mint, and until yesterday my SQLDeveloper was running smoothly, but for any reason it's simply not working anymore, i've tried updating the SQL, JDK, etc.

And the worst part is that there's simply no error displayed. All I get is

> Oracle SQL Developer
> Copyright (c) 2005, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

And that's it! It just stops and goes back to $cmd.

I've run out of ideias. Can anyone think about it?

Comment: Start it from a shell / cmd prompt - what comes back?

Comment: I wrote this for os x, but applies to linux as well https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/12/java-mac-sqldev/